# Should I disavow an article link that Googlebot thinks is a site wide link because of the way the site has implemented infinite scroll on all pages?

Tags: backlinks, disavow-links, infinite-scroll

My site has a backlink in one article of a fairly high authority site (ranks well on Google).

However, their site's design uses an infinite scroll system that is making Google think my single link is on all 3,500 individual pages of their site. In other words, my Webmaster Tools Link Profile is showing my site as having 3,500 links from their site.

Of course, I’m worried this buggy “site wide link” is holding back my site from ranking as good as it could.

Besides the link being site wide, I’ve also heard that a site wide link is more dangerous if it is a keyword instead of your brand. In this case the keyword is a generic: “source”.

Even though it’s not a keyword I need to rank for, could it be hurting the keywords I do want to rank for? BTW, it’s also a very heavily weighted keyword in my keyword profile (weighted at 75%!!!)

Finally, the linking site isn’t incredibly relevant, so it feels there’s a lot of reasons why I should remove, or disavow it.
 
My site, however, has been ranking fairly well anyway, so I'm afraid of the "If it ain't broke, don't fix it" issue.

I'm afraid to remove this massive amount of links in one fell swoop because:

1. I’ve heard that if Google sees a high percentage of links disappear all of a sudden (remember, 75% of my total!), Google can react negatively and penalize you… at least temporarily.
2. there’s a chance that the massive amount of links might be having a positive effect on my SEO since it’s not a spam link (the link itself is organic), it’s just that it’s site wide because of the site’s infinite scroll.

MAIN QUESTION: 
Is this a situation in which this link is only a potential liability and that there should be no negative effect if I disavowed it?